# Finding classes in Ruby's standard lib documentation

Tags: ruby, api

I'm looking for the `SecureRandom` class (or module?) in Ruby's [standard lib documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/) but cannot find it (Ruby 1.9.2). Since this class or module is part of the standard lib I think it must also be in the documentation. But what is the systematic to find it in the docs?

Comment: I wonder why "ri SecureRandom" in console doesn't work.

Comment: The answer to this command is only: `Nothing known about SecureRandom`.

Comment: Yep, from what I gather ri should also include the standard lib, so it's pretty weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate your docs.

```
rvm docs generate
```

But you also need to generate the stuff for the standard lib, in the ruby library folder this should reasonably work:

```
rdoc --ri *.c lib/*.rb
```

However, on my machine, I get stack level too deep when I try to do everything at once but this works:

```
USER (~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1)
$ find . -name '*.rb' -exec rdoc --ri {} \;
Parsing sources...
```

after a few minutes, everything works as expected:

```
USER (~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1)
$ ri SecureRandom
(from ~/.ri)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
= Class methods:

  base64
  hex
  random_bytes
  random_number
  urlsafe_base64
  uuid
```

Answer (score 2):

I use [APIDock](http://apidock.com/).

Failing that [google](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=securerandom&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&client=ubuntu&hs=IVW&channel=fs&source=hp&q=securerandom%20ruby&pbx=1&oq=securerandom%20ruby&aq=f&aqi=g-e1g-b1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1829l2577l0l2742l5l4l0l0l0l0l234l580l0.2.1l3l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=bdc9b0269213fa8f&biw=1920&bih=771).

http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/securerandom/1.9.2/SecureRandom

Comment: I've found the same ruby doc page with the same google query, but I wondered why I cannot find `SecureRandom` in the doc linked in my question. Looking for [`SecureRandom` on the APIDock](http://apidock.com/ruby/search?query=securerandom) site brought only 'No results found for "securerandom"'.